# Error on INSERT INTO statement

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following and getting the `error in INSERT INTO statement`.  I've done a `debug.print` and pasted back into SSMS and it works just fine so I'm really stumped.  The syntax looks fine to me but I know sometimes going from straight SQL to VBA SQL can be tricky. I had a feeling it was the `EXISTS` section and I took that out and made the appropriate edits and still got the error msg.  Any suggetions?

```
sqlstr = "INSERT INTO [database.[dbo].[table]" & _
    "(" & _
        "User_name" & _
        ",Client_Id" & _
        ",Client_Name" & _
        ",UserAccess" & _
        ",UserId" & _
    ")" & _
    "SELECT " & _
        "User_name = '" & UserName & "'" & _
        ",Client_Id = " & Me.ClientList.ItemData(ClientID) & "" & _
        ",Client_Name = '" & Me.ClientList.Column(1, ClientID) & "'" & _
        ",UserAccess = 0" & _
        ",UserId = " & UserId & "" & _
  " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [database].[dbo].[table] where UserID = " & UserId & " and Client_Id = " & Me.ClientList.ItemData(ClientID) & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Access SQL != T-SQL.

You either need to run this SQL string as a **Pass-Through query**, then it's the same as running it in SSMS.

Or translate it into Access SQL.

At the very most you must change the table names into the names of the linked tables in Access (which certainly aren't `[database].[dbo].[table]`)

If you need more help with option 2, please post the formatted result of `Debug.Print sqlstr`